# I just created a new android studio app and when i synced it, the following error messages in the image links below appeared. Any solutions?

Tags: java, android, cornerradius

The following are the images of the 13 errors which are arriving when I am trying to use android studio today. These errors have never occurred before. These are related to something called dialog Corner radius which is not being found. How can I solve this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suggest that you google each error message to see what other's have already done to solve them.

Comment: For errors such as these, it is often easier and better to just copy/paste them as text. Then you don't have to post multiple screenshots as you scroll through the errors.